# Disable all symbols characters from input field in TinyMCE editor?

Tags: javascript, tinymce, textarea, editor, symbols

I'm using TinyMCE editor, I have a text area and inside I only want text to be written. If there is any symbols like `> ? ! <` etc... It has some problem, how to disable anything that is not letters from A-Z, CAPS are fine?

This is what I have in editor file.

```js
tinyMCE.init({
    selector: "#mytextareaEdit",
});
```

I have tried looking on the NET for an answer but the closet one was:

```js
allow_conditional_comments: true
```

I think there is a command like this `allow_symbols:false;` but can't find it anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to stop people from typing any non alphabetic character into the editor you likely have to rely on key press events (`keydown` in particular) to determine if the character should be allowed.  For example:

```
setup: function(editor) {
  editor.on('keydown', function (event) {
      // console.log(event);
      if (event.keyCode === 188 || event.keyCode === 190)  {
          console.log('< or > key pressed!');
          event.preventDefault();
          event.stopPropagation();
          return false;
      }
  });
}
```

This approach would deny specific characters based on their code.  Alternatively you could allow them based on their key codes and deny anything else ... that may be easier for your use case.

Here is a running example of the above code:

http://fiddle.tinymce.com/Uqhaab

Answer (score -1):

you can disabled by using html_entity_decode.

reference link: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php